# Flutter- wrapping text

Tags: dart, flutter

I want wrap text as text grows. I searched through and tried wrap with almost everything but still text stays one line and overflows from the screen. 
Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Any help is highly appreciated!

```
Positioned(
    left: position.dx,
    top: position.dy,
    child: new Draggable(
      data: widget.index,
      onDragStarted: widget.setDragging,
      onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
        setState(() {
          position = offset;
          widget.secondCallback(offset, widget.index);
          widget.endDragging();
        });
      },
      child: new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          widget.callback(widget.caption, widget.index);
        },
        child: new Text(
            widget.caption.caption,
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: widget.caption.color,
              fontSize: widget.caption.fontSize,
            ),
          ),
      ),
      feedback: new Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: new Text(
          widget.caption.caption,
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: widget.caption.color,
              fontSize: widget.caption.fontSize),
          softWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In a project of mine I wrap `Text` instances around `Container`s. This particular code sample features two stacked Text objects.

Here's a code sample.

```
    //80% of screen width
    double c_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8;

    return new Container (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      width: c_width,
      child: new Column (
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text ("Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 ", textAlign: TextAlign.left),
          new Text ("Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2", textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[edit] Added a width constraint to the container

Comment: Thank you for the help but still not working. I think it's something to do with stack or  positioned or draggable. Because hierarchy is stack -> positioned -> draggable. Am I right?

Comment: You might try to force a fixed width to a container: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly. You just made my day!

Comment: Try the Flexible widget instead. Hardcoding containers width should not be necessary.

Comment: it didn’t work i tried so many times with it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Instead of setting a fixed width, you can use Expanded to make the container to expand to maximum width:
Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(

Comment: I think @Boni2k's answer is more... flexible. lol. the use of the Flexible widget make more sense

Comment: Perl forlks would say: "There's more than one way to do it". It served me well at the time, when Flutter was fairly new-ish. I'm glad there's now an official path.

Comment: this solution is only worked for me, others not.

Answer (score 575):

The `Flexible` does the trick

```
new Container(
       child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
               child: new Text("A looooooooooooooooooong text"))
                ],
        ));
```

This is the official doc https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-multiple-widgets-vertically-and-horizontally on how to arrange widgets.

Remember that `Flexible` and also `Expanded`, should only be used within a `Column`, `Row` or `Flex`, because of the `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`.

The solution is not the mere `Flexible`

Comment: Using Row and column for a single child widget isnt a good Idea

Comment: This also can be substituted with `Expanded()`, but `Expanded()` makes the child fill the rest of the available space. It can be observed in the Flutter's Inspector tool, to understand better.

Comment: I used the `Flexible()` widget and it wordked. You should edit your answer then it would be the accepted solution.

Comment: The Flexible does the trick, but the Container allows you to add a padding. This is the official doc https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-multiple-widgets-vertically-and-horizontally on how to arrange widgets, as @KonstantinKozirev said you can use Expanded as well.

Comment: This throws an incorrect ParentDataWidget error when the Text is nested within a container so itt's Container -> Flexible -> Text as Flexible can only be used in Rows, Columns and Flex?

Comment: Unfortunately, both `Flexible` and `Expanded ` cause the text to take up all the remaining horizontal space in a row, even when after wrapping the bounding box around the text could be "shrunk" to fit the text. This may lead to an unexpected result if you're trying to center, within a column, a row containing wrapping text.

Comment: `Row -> Flexible -> Row -> Flexible -> Text` wont work . In this case I had to use maxWidth constraint

Answer (score 121):

***Using Ellipsis***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
),
```

[image]

---

***Using Fade***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
  maxLines: 1,
  softWrap: false,
),
```

[image]

---

***Using Clip***

```
Text(
  "This is a long text",
  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
  maxLines: 1,
  softWrap: false,
),
```

[image]

---

**Note:**

If you are using `Text` inside a `Row`, you can put above `Text` inside `Expanded` like:

```
Expanded(
  child: AboveText(),
)
```

Comment: In my case, this line caused the text to not wrap to next line and instead was just getting clipped:
`overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis`

Changing it to `TextOverflow.fade` or removing the overflow tag completely solved the problem. Weird, but I guess if I need it to wrap, I shouldn't be using overflow anyways.

Answer (score 107):

Use Expanded

```
 Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(_name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  child: new Text(text),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: This. You could also use flexible without a flex (i.e. flex set to 1) in order to fill 100% of the available space.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Reason: Google advertises the same solution: codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/#8 (see Chapter Wrap long lines)

Answer (score 68):

If it's a single text widget that you want to wrap, you can either use **Flexible** or **Expanded** widgets.

```
Expanded(
  child: Text('Some lengthy text for testing'),
)
```

or

```
Flexible(
  child: Text('Some lengthy text for testing'),
)
```

For multiple widgets, you may choose **Wrap** widget. For further details checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M&vl=zh-CN)

Comment: Both solutions are not working if Text widget is a child of Column. Any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Recommending `Flexible` or `Expanded` without a single mention of `Column` / `Row` is, in my opinion, harmful.

Answer (score 23):

Try `Wrap` widget  to wrap text as text grows:

**Example:**

```dart
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.vertical, //Vertical || Horizontal
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Your Text',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
    ),
    Text(
      'Your Text',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: This solution is not working if Text widget is a child of Column. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You Can Wrap your widget with Flexible Widget and than you can set property of Text using overflow property of Text Widget.
you have to set TextOverflow.**clip**
for example:-

```
Flexible
(child: new Text("This is Dummy Long Text",
 style: TextStyle(
 fontFamily: "Roboto",
 color: Colors.black,
 fontSize: 10.0,
 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
 overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),)
```

hope this help someone :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Less code and up to the point (actual purpose of the widget)

Comment: Flexible is just dismiss all my text , not showing anything

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me! Simple and powerful! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

```
Container(
  color: Color.fromRGBO(224, 251, 253, 1.0),
  child: ListTile(
    dense: true,
    title: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          softWrap: true,
          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>
          [
            TextSpan(text: "hello: ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            TextSpan(text: "I hope this helps",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ]
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Flexible, in this case the **person.name** could be a long name (Labels and BlankSpace are custom classes that return widgets) :

```
new Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
   new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
            child: Labels.getTitle_2(person.name,
            color: StyleColors.COLOR_BLACK)),
        BlankSpace.column(3),
        Labels.getTitle_1(person.likes())
      ]),
    BlankSpace.row(3),
    Labels.getTitle_2(person.shortDescription),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `SizedBox` to hardcode the width, and `softWrap` to make new line of Text

```
SizedBox(
   width: 400,
   child: Text(
      "Really long text",
      softWrap: true,              
   ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution for a simple instance, use the `softWrap` property of the Text Widget.

With softWrap enabled:
[image]

Comment: Post actual code instead of image

Comment: It's as simple as:

const Text( 'A very long text. We need this text to move to another line instead of 
     overflowing',
     softWrap: true,
)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package:

```
 Container(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 200.0,
      maxWidth: 200.0,
      minHeight: 50.0,
      maxHeight: 150.0,
    ),
    child: AutoSizeText(
      "Your Text",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Example:
[image: Example:]

You can further constrain the text by setting `maxLines` or specify `presetFontSizes` if you wish to restrict specific font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For Anybody who tried using an Expanded or Flexible widget and it didn't work, the trick is to set your text's maxLines property to a given value > 1. Example:

```
Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text(
                        product.description!,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,

                       //Set MAXimum lines
                        maxLines: 5,
                        style: TextStyles.caption1TextStyle
                            .copyWith(fontSize: TextStyles.bodySize),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded(
         child: Text(
           'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.',
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 58),
           softWrap: false,
           maxLines: 3,
         ),
       ),
```

Utilise `Expanded` widget to set `TextOverflow.visible`

for those who want this, thankks

Answer (score -1):

wrapping text flutter

```
 Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              'This is a long text that needs to be wrapped to the next line because it cannot fit within the available space.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
              maxLines: 2, // Limit the text to 2 lines
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Use ellipsis (...) for overflow
              softWrap: true, // Enable text wrapping
            ),
          ),
        ),
```