# Flutter Center Wrapped Text

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, is it possible to center text that is wrapped?

I'm stuck with

[image: wrapped text]

In effect, I want the text to wrap but still be centered.

[image]

Comment: Already discuss in here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can just use `textAlign` property

```
Text(
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
  )
```