# How to wrap Text on AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I added sub-Appbar on my application. How to view all text on the app bar without reducing font size?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: submitRequestAppBar(context),
      body: Scaffold(
          appBar:
      PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
          child:
          AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
            leading: Container(),
            title: Text(
              widget.title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 15.0),
            ),
          ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: i think you should not use two scaffolds in one view. Here what a Scaffold is https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html. Depends on what you want to do with you second Appbar, why don't you style it inside of your (first and only) Scaffold's body?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an scroll-animation to show the text that doesn't fit the screen. You can use [this widget](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee#-readme-tab-), the ***marquee***. It's open-source so if you want to contribute you can just fork it and create a pull-request, [from here.](https://github.com/marcelgarus/marquee)

It it's only wrapping you are after and don't care about the design. Then you should look into the [solution on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text)

Comment: is it impossible to wrap text without plugin?

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: I don't know how to use on appBar on your 2nd solution

Comment: can to give example

Comment: Just copy your text part into a container with the same requirements as you see in the answer from the second post.

Comment: text in AppBar is a widget. That means you can put whatever you want there(widget).You can put marquee, container and so on. Just follow the solution for text wrapping.