# Center row content, or wrap if it's too long

Tags: flutter, centering, flutter-layout, word-wrap

I have a `Row` with an `Icon` and a `Text`. I want the content of the `Row` to be centered, i.e. the `Icon` + `Text` should be centered, with the `Icon` to the left of the `Text`. I'm doing this by setting `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` on the `Row`.

The problem is that sometimes the content of the `Text` is too long to fit on one line, and needs to be wrapped. I can do this by wrapping it in an `Expanded`, but this also has the side effect of making the `Text` occupy the entire `Row`, so now the `Icon` and `Text` will become left-adjusted instead of centered in the `Row`, even if the text content is short.

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.grey),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
              'Short text' // or 'Some very long text that won\'t fit one one line here'
          ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

How can I achieve what I want - i.e. centering the content of the `Row` while still allowing the `Text` to wrap if the text is too long to fit on one line?

Comment: Have you tried using [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html)? And I would refer to this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Row` is wrapped by `Center`.Try this.

```
Center(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.grey),
            Flexible(
                child: Text('Hello World'),
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Change `Expanded` to `Flexible`

Comment: Changing `Expanded` to `Flexible` did the trick. Instead of wrapping in `Center`, I changed `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.max`.