# Adjust new line spacing in Flutter Text Widget

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, text-widget

So, the objective was very simple, **wrap a bunch of text in a container**.
For that I followed this [Flutter- wrapping text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text) , but the new line created, **has too much space between the previous line**.

My code for the Container() with Text():

```
 description == ""
              ? SizedBox.shrink()
              : Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      new Text(
                        description,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Small note: If any descripton is given to Parent widget, I just use a SizeBox.shrink() as an "empety widget".

How it current is, with too much space:

[image: Current]

How it should be:

[image: Design Goal]

I know that 1º image is bigger, but that's not why line spacing is greater

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referred from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html). You can adjust the line spacing by changing the `height` property inside the style. **1.0** seemed fine to me but you can try setting it to **0.8**, **0.7**.

```
  Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      new Text(
                        'You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times: You have pushed the button this many times:',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,   height: 1.0 ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),),
```

Comment: The shame with this is that it adjusts the text height generally, rather than just spacing between wrapped text lines, where the text is a single widget.

Comment: @Scott I do agree but there is no other way yet.