# Break and wrap widget to next line in a row but start from extreme left of parent widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to achieve this layout
[image]

I used RichText to do this earlier([Flutter- wrapping text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text/58470417#58470417)) but now I need to use a custom Text Widget (which a library returns) with a inbuilt Text widget but unfortunately the TextSpan used with RichText accepts only TextSpan as children and not any other type of Widgets.

**When using row this happens D: which i dont need**
[image]

**and when i use a Wrap Widget this happens which i dont need either**
[image]

Comment: I think it would be impossible to do

Comment: Wrapping the `Row` inside a `Column` widget might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way,

```
  RichText(text: TextSpan(
                 children: [
                      WidgetSpan(child: Container()),
                      TextSpan(text: 'hs dhjfb jkwbfkjw hkjfhkwjk jwjbjfwkj wb')
                           ]
                        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Wrap(
  children: [
      ...splitToManyWidgets(text1),
      ...splitToManyWidgets(text2),
  ],
),

///////

List<Widget> splitToManyWidgets(String str) {
    List<Widget> result = [];
    List<String> list = str.split(" ");
    for (var element in list) {
      result.add(
        Text("$element ")
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
```