# How do i align my text to be inside a button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

i need help with my app since iam new to flutter. so i have a button that suppossed to have a text inside it, but when i run my app, the text isnt inside the button, i dont know how to fix this. so here is my app when i run it:

[image]

i use MyButton for the button and text, here is my botton code

```
_addTaskBar(){
    return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                      style: subHeadingStyle,
                      ),
                      Text("Today", 
                      style: headingStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                MyButton(label: "Add Reminder", onTap: ()=>Get.to(AddReminderPage()))
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
```

here is my MyButton code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/theme.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function()? onTap;
  const MyButton({super.key, required this.label, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child:Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Color(0xFFFB7B8E),
        ),
        child: Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

any help would mean so much to me. thankyou

Comment: Add code of MyButton

Comment: could you include MyButton class?

Comment: try to add `MyButton` class

Comment: i have added MyButton class, thankyou

Comment: for your MyButton widget, set alignment of the Container to Alignment.center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text widget in MyButton can be added to the Center widget

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/theme.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function()? onTap;
  const MyButton({super.key, required this.label, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child:Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Color(0xFFFB7B8E),
        ),
        child: Center(
      child:Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
        ),
      ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text is now aligned with the left side of the container. It only looks outside because you have a rounded button, but the text is in fact exactly inside the container.
What you might want is center the text. To center it horizontally in the column, replace `crossAxisAlignment.start` with `crossAxisAlignment.center`
To center vertically, add a line at the below this one, with `mainAxisAlignment.center`

If the text still overflow, you might need to make the button bigger

If instead you would like the text to wrap, you can put it in a `Flexible` component, like in this question: [Flutter- wrapping text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text)

Have a look at this page on how to align elements in columns and row.
https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics

Answer (score 1):

```
Center(
child: Text("add reminder"))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.