# DropDownButton selected item isn't changing in UI

Tags: dart, flutter, dropdownbutton

The objects I want to add in my `DropDownButton`:

```
class Car {
  int id;
  String make;

  Car(this.id, this.make);

  static List<Car> getCars() {
    var cars = new List<Car>();
    cars.add(Car(1, "Ford"));
    cars.add(Car(2, "Toyota"));
    cars.add(Car(3, "BMW"));

    return cars;
  }
}
```

Constructing the DropDown (StatefulWidget State class):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Car _selectedCar;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(child: getDropDown()));
  }

  Widget getDropDown() {
    var cars = Car.getCars();
    this._selectedCar = cars.first; // Default to first value in list.
    var items = cars.map((car) {
      return new DropdownMenuItem<Car>(
        value: car,
        child: new Text(car.make),
      );
    }).toList();

    return DropdownButton<Car>(
        value: this._selectedCar,
        onChanged: (Car car) {
          setState(() {
            this._selectedCar = car;
          });
        },
        items: items);
  }
}
```

`DropDownButton` Shows up correctly with first item selected, but when I select another item the UI never updates to show the new item as selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initalize list just once, because there wont be a match for DropDownList value if you init new list on every draw.

Working example found here: [Gist](http://gist.github.com/knezzz/7cc3bb75992413cb43f1d2a3328b7295)

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. It crashes with : I/flutter ( 5072): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null ||
I/flutter ( 5072): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
I/flutter ( 5072): value).length == 1': is not true.

Comment: If you want to try running, full gist of the code here: https://gist.github.com/lahsrah/0267bd0e0f6797203e4d4a7a4946219d

Comment: Oh yeah okay, You were getting new list each time so none of the objects matched.

Here is working version: https://gist.github.com/knezzz/7cc3bb75992413cb43f1d2a3328b7295

Comment: if you want please edit your answer and I will mark it as the answer to give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the `_selectedCar` variable in your `initState()` method instead of the `getDropdown()` method.

According to the code you posted, the `_selectedCar` variable gets reinitialized every time you call `setState()` since `build()` method is called.

Also you mentioned you are getting the below error when trying the solution in the first answer:

> I/flutter ( 5072): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null || I/flutter (
>   5072): items.isEmpty || value == null ||
>   items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == I/flutter (
>   5072): value).length == 1': is not true.

This is most likely because more than one items in your dropdown is getting the same value.

A possible fix can be using the `id` parameter of the `Car` object as the dropdown `value` instead of the entire object, since the `id` will be unique for each object. More detail about this error can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273157/how-to-implement-drop-down-list-in-flutter).