# How to create select option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm unable to find a way to create an input field in Flutter that would open up a drop downlist of name. Is this possible with Flutter material widgets?

just like this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement drop down list in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273157/how-to-implement-drop-down-list-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use [dropdown_formfield](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield) package:

[image]