# Select Option not display new value after select change

Tags: flutter

I got issue to display value after select option... It always display **Type All**. I've follow from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948635/12837830) but still got the problem.

[image]

```
DropdownButton(
    hint: Text('Filter All Type'),
    value: _typeDataL,
    onChanged: (_newValue) {
        setState(() {
            _typeDataL = _newValue;
            // print(typeDataL);
        });
        print(_newValue);
    },
    items: typeDataL.map((value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: value,
            child: new Text(value),
        );
    }).toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code,

```
String? selectedValue = "Your init value";
var typeDataL = ["Your init value", "Option1", "Option2", "Option3"];

 DropdownButton(
              hint: const Text('Filter All Type'),
              value: selectedValue,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: typeDataL.map((value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
```

Your valueList should contain initial value, same as initial selectedValue and valueList should not contain duplicate values.